# Regex - Match versus Groups

Tags: c#, regex

I am sorry in advance if this would fall under duplicates but I could not see these answered my questions.

Could you please help and explain:

1. Where is the match or capture only for `name` held? The initial part of the pattern `[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+` does not show it between brackets so I understand it won't be a group, how then is `name` captured and held as a component of `Match 0`?
2. If I replace the string `t2` to `name@domain.com alt@yahoo.net` and pattern to `^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.\ ]+@(([A-Za-z0-9\-])+\.)+([A-Za-z\-])+)+$`

   - I would expect 2 matches: One for each full email address. Output only shows 1 match holding both separated by a space, why?
   - How should the pattern read to get 2 matches or would the string need to be different for this pattern?
   - I don't see the consistency in the Group output because it does not show another Group holding capture `0=com` and capture `1=net`, similarly to Group 2 holding `domain.` and `yahoo.` captures, why?
   - Group 3 captures seem to hold the captures of the Group 2 Capture 0 and 1, is that how hierarchies work, there are captures of captures of groups?

#### Code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string t2 = "name@domain.com";
        string p2 = @"^[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.\ ]+@(([A-Za-z0-9\-])+\.)+([A-Za-z\-])+$";

        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(t2, p2);
        GroupCollection gc;
        int groupIndex = 0;
        int matchIndex = 0;
        int captureIndex = 0;

        foreach (Match nextMatch in matches)
        {
            gc = nextMatch.Groups;
            Console.WriteLine("Match {0} holds: {1}", matchIndex, nextMatch.Value);
            matchIndex++;
            foreach (Group g in gc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Group {0} holding: {1}", groupIndex, g.ToString());
                groupIndex++;

                foreach (Capture capture in g.Captures)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tCapture {0} holds {1}", captureIndex, capture.ToString());
                    captureIndex++;
                }
                captureIndex = 0;
            }
            groupIndex = 0;
        }
        matchIndex = 0;
    }
```

Output for the above code:

```
Match 0 holds: name@domain.com
Group 0 holding: name@domain.com
Capture 0 holds name@domain.com
Group 1 holding: domain.
Capture 0 holds domain.
Group 2 holding: n
Capture 0 holds d
Capture 1 holds o
Capture 2 holds m
Capture 3 holds a
Capture 4 holds i
Capture 5 holds n
Group 3 holding: m
Capture 0 holds c
Capture 1 holds o
Capture 2 holds m
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Output if string `t2 = "name@domain.com alt@yahoo.net";` and string `p2 = @"^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.\ ]+@(([A-Za-z0-9\-])+\.)+([A-Za-z\-])+)+$"`;

```
Match 0 holds: name@domain.com alt@yahoo.net
Group 0 holding: name@domain.com alt@yahoo.net
Capture 0 holds name@domain.com alt@yahoo.net
Group 1 holding:  alt@yahoo.net
Capture 0 holds name@domain.com
Capture 1 holds  alt@yahoo.net
Group 2 holding: yahoo.
Capture 0 holds domain.
Capture 1 holds yahoo.
Group 3 holding: o
Capture 0 holds d
Capture 1 holds o
Capture 2 holds m
Capture 3 holds a
Capture 4 holds i
Capture 5 holds n
Capture 6 holds y
Capture 7 holds a
Capture 8 holds h
Capture 9 holds o
Capture 10 holds o
Group 4 holding: t
Capture 0 holds c
Capture 1 holds o
Capture 2 holds m
Capture 3 holds n
Capture 4 holds e
Capture 5 holds t
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: *"how then is "name" captured and held as a component of Match 0?"*: Match 0 is the entire string matched by the regular expression. `^[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.\ ]+` is part of the regular expression, as you can observe by looking. Therefore, it is matched.

Comment: *"**I would expect** 2 matches, one for each full email address."* -- You expect that because you didn't read the documentation and find out what `^` means. Go read it now. I'm voting to close because "Pleas please read the docs to me out loud" isn't a programming question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, thanks for your first comment, I can see it matched at match 0 in the output I've pasted, but thought it'd be held as a subcomponent of the entire match 0 somewhere similar to groups/captures, I infer and see in debug that if this part is in () it shows the group it's held in, otherwise it only shows in Match 0. On your second comment, my notes on ^ say beginning of input text but if  remove "^" in @"^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.\ ]+@(([A-Za-z0-9\-])+\.)+([A-Za-z\-])+)+$" I get the same output, where should I be looking?

Comment: Hi @zᴉɹɥƆ the change is revealing, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `Match` covers the matching of the entire regex. The regex can be applied to the given string.

`Group`s are part of that `Match` and `Capture`s are (if you specified multiple occurences of a group like (someRegex)+ ) all `Capture`s of that `Group`. Try changing `([A-Za-z\-])+` to `([A-Za-z\-]+)` and see the difference!

Examples:

`\w*(123)\w*` on `"asdsa123asdf"`

1. Match -> asdsa123asdf
2. Group -> 123 *(== last capture)*
3. Captures -> 123

`\w*([123])+\w*` on `"asdsa123asdf"`

1. Match -> asdsa123asdf
2. Group -> 3 *(== last capture)*
3. Captures -> 1, 2, 3

There are multiple sites to test and show details of your regex, i.e. https://regexr.com or https://regex101.com